# Problem with \begrelateddelim, punctuation tracker, and parentheses in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'm having a problem with related entries in `biblatex` when they are started within parentheses.

`\begrelateddelim` is inserted after the first field in the related entry, since it isn't included at the beginning of the related entry in this case.

So the following MWE places a semi-colon after the `author` in the related entry. i.e.,

> [1] Author1. *Title1*. 2017 (Author2; *Title2*. 2018).

The desired output is:

> [1] Author1. *Title1*. 2017 (Author2. *Title2*. 2018).

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
  author = {Author1},
  title = {Title1},
  volume = {2},
  date = {2017},
  related = {book2}
}
@book{book2,
  author = {Author2},
  title = {Title2},
  date = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\begrelateddelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit
  \printdate
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\togglefalse{bbx:related}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \usebibmacro{related:init}%
       \usebibmacro{related}}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{book1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, the `related` macro makes use of `\printunit{\begrelateddelim}`. The "first level" approach would be to patch the macro and substitute it for `\setunit`, but there's probably a reason for `\printunit` there...

Comment: Yup, short of the above (untested, and likely unwise) idea, I also cannot untie the knot.

Comment: @gusbrs, thanks. I'll wait and see what moewe has to say before patching the `related` macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the field format `related` or `related:<relatedtype>`. Additionally I redefined `\begrelateddelim` to be `\addspace` because I could not see where the semicolon should enter the equation here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
  author = {Author1},
  title = {Title1},
  volume = {2},
  date = {2017},
  related = {book2}
}
@book{book2,
  author = {Author2},
  title = {Title2},
  date = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\begrelateddelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{related}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit
  \printdate
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{book1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

You'll find that the `related` block has exactly the same form as in the standard drivers and that the `\togglefalse{bbx:related}` is not needed any more.

---

So what was the problem about?

It is mainly caused by

```
 \printtext[parens]{%
   \usebibmacro{related:init}%
   \usebibmacro{related}}
```

Internally `\usebibmacro{related}` also calls a `\printtext` (the one whose format we define with `\DeclareFieldFormat{related}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` or `\DeclareFieldFormat{related:<relatedtype>}{\mkbibparens{#1}}`). Additionally, `\usebibmacro{related}` also sets the `\begrelateddelim` in a printunit before it starts the `\printtext`. So we end up with

```
\printtext[parens]{%
  \printunit{\begrelateddelim}%
  \printtext[related]{%
    ...
  }%
}%
```

Because nothing is printed in between the two `\printtext` statements, the punctuation buffer survives into the second `\printtext`. You can see the same effect with

```
\printtext[parens]{%
  \printunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext[related]{%
    \printtext{foo}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printtext{goo}}}%
```

The first `\printtext[parens]` prints and flushes the punctuation tracker before it. Then `\addperiod\space` is added to the tracker with `\printunit`. Now `\printtext[related]` prints, but for the punctuation tracker nothing was printed before it. Hence, `\addperiod\space` survives and even overrides the `\addcomma\space` later on.

---

Note that

```
 \printtext[parens]{%
   \usebibmacro{related:init}%
   \usebibmacro{related}}
```

has another problem: It doesn't check if there is a `related` entry at all. So it will print empty parentheses in that case (cite `book2` to see the problem). The `\togglefalse{bbx:related}` could only remedy this if `book2` was printed as a related entry of `book2`, but not if it is printed in its own right. `\usebibmacro{related}` has the checks necessary to avoid this built in already.

Comment: That all said, I'm not sure if we really need a `\printunit` here anyway, a `\setunit` could be enough (if no one issued a `\printunit` before)....

Comment: You make it look simple. :) +1 It actually still took me quite some time to understand, even after you explained, that `\printtext[\bbx@tempa]{%` was doing `\printtext[related]{%`...

Comment: Useful. But sadly my MWE is too simple :(. I actually have more than just the related entry within the parentheses. I use it for particularly complex reference types in `biblatex-sbl`. The semicolon was simply something other than `\newunitpunct` in this MWE. I'll close this off and make a more complex MWE in a new question.

Comment: @DavidPurton In this case, wouldn't the `begrelatedloop` and `endrelatedloop` macros be useful? They are defined empty by default, but may provide the hooks you need.

Comment: @gusbrs. Hmmm. Good thought. I'll try things out later.

Comment: @gusbrs, nice! Worked perfectly. Thanks all.

Comment: @DavidPurton Ah, great to hear that! But that's just testimony of how carefully crafted `biblatex` is.  ;)  The hook is there, even though it is not used, but because it "might be needed". Someone has thought of you!